# How to append the div before the div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I append the div or html element before the specified div id?

```
<== Here I want to insert the New div tag (<div id='tt'>test</div>)
Div1

Div1 End
```

I tried to placed the wrap(), prepend() but both are not used.

Comment: is div1 the id of the div

Comment: You need to use .before() or .insertBefore()

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It takes about an hour, and repays you that time *immediately*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**before()**](http://api.jquery.com/before/).

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements

```js
$('#div1').before('<div id="tt">test</div>');
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#tt {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
```

Comment: You can also select an element on the page and insert it before another:

$( "#div1" ).before( $( "<div id='tt'>test</div>" ) );