# How to append HTML block and insert before a specific element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button which on click It will append a hidden HTML block, before a certain element. I know this is a very simple question but I was struggling to find out the correct way of doing it. Following is my snippet.

```
$("#layout-full-width").click(function(){
       $('#appendFullWidth').html().append().before('#layout-container');
});
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="layout-full-width">Append</button>

<div id="#layout-container">content</div>

<div class="hidden" id="appendFullWidth">
<div class="col-md-12 layout-fullwidth text-center m-y-10">
    <div class="layout-inner-container">
        <a id="layoutRemove" class="btn btn-circle-table red btn-alignment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash m-a-0"></i></a>
        <p class="m-a-0 layout-inner-text"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hover to add a component</p>
        <ul class="list-inline layout-components">
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Textarea"><a class="layoutTextArea"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Title"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-font" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Question"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Attachment"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Embed"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="URL"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tags"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to append #appendFullWidth html content before #layout-container element. The above code does not work.

Comment: please see the last snippet. #insertHere for an example

Comment: share your html code

Comment: See following code.

$('#appendFullWidth').html().append().insertBefore('#layout-container');

I need to append the html content of #appendFullWidth before #layout-container element

Comment: how we supose to know your html structure?

Comment: posible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826301/how-to-append-the-div-before-the-div-using-jquery

Comment: `$('#appendFullWidth').html()` returns the `innerHTML` of the `#appendFullWidth` element, which has no `append()` method. Did you look at any of the - remarkably good - documentation? Please: read the documentation of the methods you're trying to use: [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/), [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), [`insertBefore()`](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $.html() method in jQuery give you html string and not the jq element.

and now the solution:
There is 1 mistake in you html code id of you div is `#layout-container` it should be `layout-container` without the #.
After changing this following code should work as you expect.

```
$("#layout-full-width").click(function(){
       var toAppend=$('#appendFullWidth').children().eq(0);
       toAppend.prependTo('#layout-container'); 

});
```

Here is working js bin link.https://jsbin.com/ninonul/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is working fine. However I want to keep adding the html blocks over and over when clicking on the #layout-full-width.

Comment: prepend() method removes element from first place, so there is nothing to append second time. However this can be solve by .clone() method.
`toAppend.clone().prependTo('#layout-container'); `
Also updated the jsbin on this link https://jsbin.com/mazokuq/edit?html,js,output.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you